# Streaming versus buffering video

Tags: video, video-streaming

At what point should you use a video streaming server versus putting a video file on a regular web server and have it played back via a player such as JW Player? Is this solely based upon file size? If so, where is the cutoff point to go to a streaming solution? I understand why streaming would be better, but I am curious if anyone has some first-hand knowledge of pain points around not streaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that it's really only been an issue for me when I'm working with videos that are expected to not start at the beginning and flow through. If your users are going to be skipping to information at specific intervals, streaming is going to be a big benefit. This also applies to longer videos where someone may or may not watch the whole thing at the first visit but may return and watch the rest later.

Answer (score 0):

Progresive download of video is feasible when bitrate is low in comparison to the device and network capacity. Bitrate and resolution (screen size) are the most important parameters for a video to play smoothly without rebuffering.
A video total file size cam be high due the video's duration. What it really matters is the amount of bits being sent over the network and played at the client side per second.